# Integral equation and differential equation

Tags: integration, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

We have $y'=By+G(y)$, where $B=\left[ 
        \begin{array}{cc}
         P & 0\\ 
         0 & Q
         \end{array}
      \right] $ and Let $U(t)=\left[ 
        \begin{array}{cc}
         e^{Pt} & 0\\ 
         0 & 0
         \end{array}
      \right] $ and $V(t)=\left[ 
        \begin{array}{cc}
         0 & 0\\ 
         0 & e^{Qt}
         \end{array}
      \right] $. Consider the integral equation
$u(t,a)=U(t)a+\int_{0}^{t}U(t-s)G(u(s,a))ds-\int_{t}^{\infty}V(t-s)G(u(s,a))ds$

And i don't understand why if $u(t,a)$ is a continuous solution of this integral equation, then it is a soution of the differential equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (at least due to my calculations)
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(t-s)g(s)\,ds = f(0)g(t) + \int_0^tf'(t-s)g(s)\,ds
$$
and therefore also
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_t^\infty f(t-s)g(s)\,ds = -f(0)g(t) + \int_t^\infty f'(t-s)g(s)\,ds
$$
Using these rules when differentiating $u$ with respect to $t$ you get
\begin{align*}
u_t = U'(t)a + U(0)G(u) + &\int_0^t U'(t-s)G(u(s,a))\,ds + V(0)G(u)\\
&- \int_t^\infty V'(t-s)G(u(s,a))\,ds.
\end{align*}
Now, $U'(t) = BU(t)$, $V'(t) = BV(t)$, and $U(0) + V(0) = I$. Hence, indeed,
\begin{align*}
u_t
&= BU(t)a + G(u) + B\int_0^t U(t-s)G(u(s,a))\,ds - B\int_t^\infty V(t-s)G(u(s,a))\,ds\\
&= Bu + G(u).
\end{align*}